# iptables rule between networks is not working

Tags: iptables, netcat

I have a scenario where a router connects 2 networks, so I have this machines with this interfaces:
The virtual machine 1 that work as a router:

```
eth1: 193.136.200.254 
eth2: 192.168.10.254 
eth3: 24.200.220.254
```

Virtual machine 2:

```
eth1: 192.168.10.2 
eth1:0: 192.168.10.3
```

...
Virtual machine 3:

```
eth1: 24.200.220.2
eth1:0: 24.200.220.3
```

In the virtual machine 3 i have a ip associated with a mysql service (24.200.220.3) and I want that clients connected to a server in the virtual machine 2 (196.168.10.2) should be able to connect the server (24.200.220.3) in the virtual machine 3. And drop all of the other communications between networks.
Im trying to do this using this iptables rules:

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 24.200.220.3 -s 192.168.10.2 --sport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 24.200.220.3 -d 192.168.10.2 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

To test this rules in the virtual machine 3 Im running the command:
nc  -l 24.200.220.3 3306
In the virtual machine 2 Im running:
nc  24.200.220.3 3306
Then I write a random word in one machine but it is not appearing in the other machine. So it isnt working. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a sport/dport of 3306 but then trying to connect over 22?

Comment: And what about NAT rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's little mistake. If you use database destination​ IP address, then you need to use destination database port with it. And do it the same for source IP and port.

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 24.200.220.3 -s 192.168.10.2 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 24.200.220.3 -d 192.168.10.2 --sport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```